# Where am I going with the glider?

Tags: brothers-tale-of-two-sons

I got to this part with a glider, but every time I get out of the cave a group of birds come out of nowhere and destroy the glider. I try to make my way to the stranded cliff ahead, but I always simply crash into it failing the part.

Where should I be aiming with the glider?

(Image added to recognize the part easier)
[image: Glider in a valley]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're aiming for a platform on the right side of the castle ahead. Dodge the stranded cliff and there will be a burst of wind that will carry you the rest of the way.

I didn't manage to get a screenshot while I was gliding as I had to keep both of my hands on the controller, but here's an image from above the platform.

[image: Platform from above]